# Does converting a float to a double and back to float give the same value in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

Assume in the following code

```
float f1 = ...;
double d1 = static_cast<double>(f1);
float f2 = static_cast<float>(d1);

ASSERT( f1 == f2 );
```

the variable `f1` is initialized to something which is not a NaN. Is the assertion then guaranteed to hold by the C++ standard?

Comment: And otherwise? Why not for NaNs?

Comment: NaNs never compare equal. And I think the answer otherwise is implementation dependent.

Comment: Writing this kind of code is nonsensical as presented in the snippet.  In practice you'll do something with the converted double value.  Which might be invariant to the value on paper but will make it slightly different from the original float value on the machine.  The more you do with it the more rounding error will accumulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some clues but not the answer:

> 4.6 A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type double. The value is unchanged. This conversion is called floating point promotion.
>   ...
>
> 4.8 A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point type. *If the source value can be exactly represented in the destination type*, the result of the conversion is that exact
>   representation. If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values.

Comment: Actually, this does answer it, if you assume IEEE754 arithmetic (i.e. `is_iec559` is true), as every binary32 (`float`) can be represented exactly as binary64 (`double`), excluding the issue that `NaN != NaN`, of course.

Comment: For completeness, 3.9.1/8: "The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`". So there's no need to assume anything beyond a conforming implementation.

Comment: @hyde The text appears in the C++ 2011 standard (section 4).